# DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations using Mathematica and an error occured:

> DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions.

Here's my code.

```
f = 100000;
s = 1;
DSolve[
 {
  X'[t] == -s*X[t]*w[t] + s*Z[t]*y[t] - 2 s*X[t]^2 - f*Iz[t]*X[t] + 
    2 f*Ix[t] + 3 f*Ix[t]*Z[t],
  Y'[t] == -s*Y[t]*x[t] + s*W[t]*z[t] - f*Iw[t]*Y[t] - 2 s*Y[t]^2 + 
    2 f*Iy[t] + 3 f*Iy[t]*W[t],
  Z'[t] == -s*Z[t]*y[t] + s*X[t]*w[t] - 2 s*Z[t]^2 + 2 f*Iz[t] + 
    3 f*Iz[t]*X[t] - f*Ix[t]*Z[t],
  W'[t] == -s*W[t]*z[t] - 2 s*W[t]^2 + 2 f*Iw[t] + 3 f*Iw[t]*Y[t] + 
    s*Y[t]*x[t] - f*Iy[t]*W[t],
  x'[t] == -s*X[t]*x[t] - s*Y[t]*x[t] + s*emp1[t],
  y'[t] == -s*Y[t]*y[t] - s*Z[t]*y[t] + s*emp2[t],
  z'[t] == -s*Z[t]*z[t] - s*W[t]*z[t] + s*emp3[t],
  w'[t] == -s*W[t]*w[t] - s*X[t]*w[t] + s*emp4[t],
  Ix'[t] == s*X[t]^2 - f*Ix[t] - f*Ix[t]*Z[t],
  Iy'[t] == s*Y[t]^2 - f*Iy[t] - f*Iy[t]*W[t],
  Iz'[t] == s*Z[t]^2 - f*Iz[t] - f*Iz[t]*X[t],
  Iw'[t] == s*W[t]^2 - f*Iw[t] - f*Iw[t]*Y[t],
  E0'[t] == -f*E0[t]*x[t] + f*E1[t]*y[t] - f*E0[t]*z[t] + f*E1[t]*w[t],
  E1'[t] == -E0'[t],

  emp1'[t] == 0,
  emp2'[t] == 0,
  emp3'[t] == 0,
  emp4'[t] == 0,
  emp1[0] == 100,
  emp2[0] == 100,
  emp3[0] == 100,
  emp4[0] == 100,
  X[0] == 1,
  Y[0] == 1,
  Z[0] == 0,
  W[0] == 0,
  x[0] == 0,
  y[0] == 0,
  z[0] == 0,
  w[0] == 0,
  Ix[0] == 0,
  Iy[0] == 0,
  Iz[0] == 0,
  Iw[0] == 0,
  E0[0] == 1,
  E1[0] == 0

  },
 {X[t], Y[t], Z[t], W[t], x[t], y[t], z[t], w[t], Ix[t], Iy[t], Iz[t],
   Iw[t], E0[t], E1[t]},
 t]
```

I've tried to clear all the variables before using DSolve,but it didn't work at all.

Could someone help me?Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason emp1 through emp4 are not in the {} list on the second-to-last line?

Comment: Ah...that's exactly the reason why it didn't work...Thank you!

Comment: Ubetcha happy it worked

Answer (score 0):

emp1[t] through emp4[t] needed to be added to the list of functions in the curly braces on the second to last line.